Error installing AzCore System 32 Accessing file
I am installing azerothcore and Im kind of a noob at doing this stuff. Im confident I followed the steps up to step four correctly and encountered no errors, but when attempting to run the file "create mysql" on the sql workbench using the "run sql file" option
https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/data/sql/create/create_mysql.sql
Inside of sql, I am getting an error,
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\MBDIS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpupgnhc86.cnf'
Ive gone inside of the local temp files and deleted the file but every time it just spawns a new error with a new file. I could use some guidance on how to proceed. Thanks!
Attempted adding the file explorer option to launch different instances - nothing changed
attempted using the raw files and the download button on github - no change
task manager closed sql and retried, rebooted comp - no change

just create the database and put in the mysql credentials in the config, the authserver and the worldserver will create these by its own

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
